# Using ngModel with empty Object

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the state of the art solution for adding values to an empty instance of a class? For example, I am having a User Class and I want to create a new user. In my component, I am instantiating an empty User Object "user: User;". The properties are beeing set with the constructor, some of the parameters are optional. Now if I want to bind the input forms to the empty/undefined class instance via ngModel, this (of course) does not work. I could set default values in my component but that doesn't seem to be the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your reactive form and set them as the blank string. Also do the same for the optional fields as well.

You need to tell these are an optional field or else angular will not understand it.

```
public username: AbstractControl;
public password: AbstractControl;
this.userForm = new FormGroup({
  username: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
});
```

View code:

```
<input type="text" name="username" 
   formControlName="username" class="form-control form-control-danger"
   id="username" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
```

Displaying form value:

```
<div>{{username.value || ''}}</div>
```

if the binding value is null or undefined, without setting it to a blank string, it will throw an error.